# Odoo 8 / Add field in sale order lines

Tags: odoo-8

I want to add a column in sale.order.line.

So i inherit the class :

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class MySaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    my_code = fields.Char("My code", default="AAA")
```

So, i inherit the view :

```
<record id="sale_order_view_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">my.sale.order.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="50" />
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree//field[@name='product_id']" position="before">
            <field name="my_code" />
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

The column is correctly added but when i add a product, the column stays empty (not with "AAA" content).

I also tried to add my field in the sale.order.line view, but it doesn't appear :

```
<record id="sale_view_order_line_form2_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">my.sale.view.order.line.form2.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_line_form2"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="product_id" position="after">
            <field name="my_code" />
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Is there something special to do with this module ?

Comment: One step more is required. In __openerp__.py add your xml file into data section.